# Are there any CryptoNote Monero forks that have a company backing the project?

Tags: monero-forks

I'm doing some research on Monero / CryptoNote forks where they have had an ICO or private sale and is backed by a company, like how Zcash is backed by a company and has a payroll.

Comment: I believe Electronium has (had ?) a company behind it. So payroll does not bring competence :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still no reply, so I'll post the one I know of, but there might be more.

Electroneum is a fork of Monero, which eschews development in favour of marketing. As https://electroneum.com/about/company/ shows, they have a company.

For those who might be tempted to click on the above, this fork is mostly a scam. See https://captainaltcoin.com/electroneum-price-prediction. It's basically a centralized premined coin with all flash and no trousers, and its "phone mining" does not actually mine, it just wastes your electricity and the company pays you for it. They're basically marketers and liars.